# python classification without having to impute missing values

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-imputation

I have a dataset that is working nicely in weka. It has a lot of missing values represented by '?'. Using a decision tree, I am able to deal with the missing values.

However, on sci-kit learn, I see that the estimators can't used with data with missing values. Is there an alternative library I can use instead that would support this?

Otherwise, is there a way to get around this in sci-kit learn?

Comment: And do you know what is weka doing with the missing values? Honestly I have no idea about weka, I just googled about it and found [this](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/mooc/dataminingwithweka/slides/Class5-DataMiningWithWeka-2013.pdf). If you get to know what you are actually doing in weka with your missing values, you will probably be able to replicate the same in scikit-learn. Hope it helps.